# How do I change the text color of a ListView item when a value inside an ArrayList is equals to a certain value in Android?

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

I want to change the text color of students who were absent in a class list.

I have

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> studentList = studentList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

and placed Strings inside

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("idno", sidno);
map.put("fullname", sfullname);
map.put("attendance", attendance);

studentList.add(map);
```

I placed the `studentList` in a listview using a SimpleAdapter like this

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(CheckAttendanceActivity.this, studentList, R.layout.list_students, new String[]{"idno", "fullname", "attendance"}, new int[]{R.id.idno, R.id.fullname, R.id.attendance});
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

It displays the the list of students perfectly but I want to change the text color of the students who has `attendance == "absent"` from the `studentList` ArrayList. How do I do that?

Comment: create a custom adapter for that..and  change background of position according to text..

Comment: Sorry, any sample codes? I'm still new to Android.

Comment: Check [Android-List-View](https://github.com/mohit008/Android-List-View)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.your_item_layout, parent, false);
    }
    ....
    if (getItem(position).get("attendance").equals("absent")) {   
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(getContext().getColor(R.color.bg_color_absent));
    } else {      
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(getContext().getColor(R.color.bg_color_normal));
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Just one thing though, the text is now lost. What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

In your `Adapter`'s `getView` method, check if `attendance == "absent"` and then change the background color